# how to check files/images which are more than 400 KB

Tags: media

Related to QA part of our Drupal site performance, we need to make sure that size of images on the site are not more than 400kb.

I know there will validation and configs we can use while uploading images to site. but for already existing, is there any way to find out images size which are more than specified limit?

A non-code solution would be preferred.

Comment: in which version drupal 7 or 8

Comment: @vijay its for D7 site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try direct SQL query

```
select fid, filename from file_managed where filemime like 'image/%' and filesize > 400000;
```

Comment: Hi @Rupesh 

Thanks a lot.. could you please confirm, will this test for all files inside default/files?

Comment: Yes, All files those were uploaded from drupal.